# Problem with the explicit construction of the Galois group of $x^4-x^2+1$

Tags: abstract-algebra, galois-theory

I am very new to Galois theory, so this question might be a bit stupid: Let $f \in \mathbb{Q}[x]$ be given by $f(x) = x^4-x^2+1$.

Using substitution, one gets that the zeros of $f$ are
\begin{align*}
\alpha_1 &= \sqrt{ \frac{1+i\sqrt{3}}{2}},\\
\alpha_2 &= -\alpha_1,\\
\alpha_3 &= \sqrt{ \frac{1-i\sqrt{3}}{2}},\\
\alpha_4 &= -\alpha_3.\\
\end{align*}

So we see that for any automorphism $\phi$ of the roots (i.e. element of the Galois group of $f$), we have $\phi(\alpha_2)=-\phi(\alpha_1)$ and $\phi(\alpha_4)-=\phi(\alpha_2)$. Thus, after defining $\phi(\alpha_1)$ and $\phi(\alpha_3)$, the automorphism is already determined. So the possible automorphisms (written as permutations) should be:
\begin{align*}
e, (12), (34),(12)(34),(13)(24),(14)(23),(1324),(1423)
\end{align*}
My reasoning for the last two permutations is that the map $\alpha_1 \longmapsto \alpha_3$, $\alpha_3\longmapsto \alpha_2$  can uniquely be extended to all roots by $\alpha_2\longmapsto -\alpha_3=\alpha_4$ and $\alpha_4\longmapsto - \alpha_2 = \alpha_1$, which would result in $(1324)$ (and similar for $(1423)$).

However, all sources I could check say that the Galois group is isomorphic to the Klein four group generated by $(12)(34)$ and $(14)(23)$. So basically there cannot be any elements of degree four, i.e. $(1324)$ and $(1423)$ are not part of the Galois group. But why not?

Comment: In fact, $\alpha_1 = \pm \frac{1}{2} (\sqrt{3} + i)$.  So for example if you choose $\alpha_1 = \frac{1}{2} (\sqrt{3} + i)$ and $\alpha_3 = \frac{1}{2} (\sqrt{3} - i)$, then the images of $\alpha_1$ and $\alpha_3$ are restricted by the fact that $\alpha_1 \alpha_3 = 1$.